# Why this loop is not working?

Tags: c++

```
while(a!=1&&c!=1)
{
    r=rand()%2;
    if(r==0)
    {
        cout<<"Cruz"<<endl;
        if(a==1)
        {
            c=0;
        }
        c++;
    }
    else if(r==1)
    {
        if(a>1)
        {
            a=0;
        }
        cout<<"Cara"<<endl;
        a++;
    }
    b++;
}
```

I don't know why but this loop always exits when one of the two conditions is false... and I need when both are false.
Does anyone know why is this happening?

Comment: Time to use a debugger.

Comment: Where are your declarations for `a` and `c`? Are they initialised?

Comment: int r,a,b=0,c=0;

:/ idk what to do

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you want an `||` instead of a `&&` because you want it to continue if *either* of them are true statements. (alternatively, and this would be probably more coherent, you could do:`!(a==1||c==1)`)

Comment: @Vladys So that you want it too keep looping `while` a is not 1 *or* b is not 1. Right?

Comment: @Julian mmmm I want to keep looping while a and c are not 1

Comment: if you want it to exit when they are both equal to `1` than do `while(a==1&&b==2)` the `!=` means not equals and that's what you're using

Comment: @Vladys You keep contradicting yourself. If it keeps looping while a *and* c are not 1, it will stop looping when either one isn't 1. If you want to sleep when both your homework *and* your chores are done, you have to stay up `while` either your homework *or* your chores aren't done. Right?

Comment: if you want to keep looping when both are not `1` the loop should exit after one iteration because one of them will equal `1` and the other will equal `0` hence my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

After the `while` statement, you explain the condition that must stay true *while* the code continues to loop. Since you want to exit when `a` *and* `b` have some property, you need to keep looping `while` either `a` *or* `b` does not have that property.

Say you can't go to sleep until both your homework and your chores are done. That means you need to stay awake `while` either your homework *or* your chores aren't done.

Answer (score 0):

The logical and operation only returns true when both the conditions are met. If you require the loop to work please use the logical OR operator that returns true when any one of the conditions are met. Please see the below truth table. Please check if you are using the correct logical operator